# How to debug jni code from ant task?

Tags: java, linux, debugging, ant, java-native-interface

Using java 8.  I have a junit test that works properly on Windows and fails on linux. Same code, just compiled for different platforms. Call goes from java to jni to a third lib (both written in-house).  I want to debug the call at the jni and lib levels on Linux so I can see what differences there might be in the variables, return values, etc.

On Windows, this is a snap: run test from IntelliJ, set breakpoint just before it hits jni call, fire up Visual Studio and attach to the proper java process and set a breakpoint within.  Let it run and watch, observe as I need.

How do I do the same thing on Linux?  Specifically, the debugging the jni and lib?  I can run the test from ant but am open to trying other ways to run it on Linux.

Comment: gdb might be good to use

Comment: Can you shed some further light?  I tried running ant from gdb, but it says (about ant): "file format not recognized".  Carrying on, I tried to set a breakpoint on a method I wanted to stop in and it told me I had "no symbol table loaded. Use file command". So I entered "file /path/to/libxxx.so", then typed 'run -f junit.xml".  It segfaulted as it tried to run the libxx.so file.

Comment: huh? you cant run ant from gdb, it sounded like you wanted to call gdb from ant

Comment: also use, you have to compile with certain commands in gdb to get everything working correctly, it is the old command line debugger for gcc.

Comment: Why can I not run ant from gdb - is it not just an executable to run?  I could break the junit code out to let me build/run it from java itself. Any tutorials on doing this type of debugging, or am I the first to debug a lib loaded by jni within a junit test?

Comment: why would you run ant from gdb?

Comment: also once jni code is called the jvm is left and native code is entered so you can't really hook in from java any easy way

Comment: Why.. because It's how I'm launching the test... but I could do that another way if it makes more sense to do so; I'm not bound to debugging this soley via ant, but, since all the pieces are in place, I thought to myself: "fire up gdb and debug it".  On windows, like I indicated, I'd just attach visual studio to the java process (which I have running in intellij and paused at a breakpoint) and debug away.  Problem is.. it works on windows.  LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using Eclipse with the CDT plugin. The procedure is basically the same:
1. Start the Java project and stop it with a breakpoint in the beginning
2. Run the Cpp library code, attaching the Java process just started

Follow this tutorial for setting it up. The tutorial is for Windows, but you can follow it closely for Unix.
http://codeandme.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/jni-made-easy.html

I'm using a Mac to do this. I just have a little problem right after attaching the Lib on the Java process, I have to wait a bit for it to startup, then click on the Cpp process (in the Eclipse Debug view) and resume the cpp process before going back to the Java process and resume it. After that the debug runs normally and stops on any Cpp breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but I had just done this yesterday. So I thought I'd share...

The first thing you need to do is build your .so library with all the debugging info. I used these flags: `-g -D DEBUG -O0`. This will allow you to see your source code in gdb.

Next, set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory where your shared library exits.

Now, you can attach gdb to your ant test by running 3 commands from the terminal in quick succession:

first: run your ant test:

```
$ ant <test> &
```

then: get the pid of your test:

```
$ ps -ef | grep java
```

finally: attach to the process:

```
$ gdb -p <pid>
```

things to note:

1. run your ant test in the background (with `&`) so that you can quickly run the `ps` command.
2. If your test test finishes quickly (less than 30 seconds) then, I would consider putting `Thread.sleep(30000);` in the begining of your java code, before your first JNI call. This is so that you have enough time to attach gdb to the process before the test exits.